# Wordpress Post Categories Suddenly Disabled

Tags: wordpress

In a Wordpress website that I an developing, the categories are suddenly disabled. all existing categories have been removed and I am not able to add a new category.

I tried to install Site Health Checker plugin and enabled Troubleshooting Mode. After enabling it, all the categories are retrieved and everything went back to normal.

However, when I disable Site Health Checker and then disable all plugins and activated TwentyTwentyOne plugin, the issue has once again persisted.

Not sure if this has already been asked by others but after googling for hours, it seems that no one has the same issue.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Well, it's very likely another plugin (or some code in your theme) is causing this. Try following the [Troubleshooting](https://make.wordpress.org/support/handbook/appendix/troubleshooting-using-the-health-check/#troubleshooting) instructions to try and identify which plugin(s) is/are causing this problem.

Comment: @cabrerahector I already did that. I disabled all the plugins and then switched to default WP Theme. But the categories are still gone.